# Delete to tab boundaries in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1

Tags: intellij-idea

When I press <kbd>tab</kbd> IntelliJ inserts two spaces (which is what I want), but when I press <kbd>delete</kbd> IntelliJ only removes one space at a time. How do I make it delete to the tab boundaries instead of just one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to solve this problem too, but it appears that it is not possible at the moment.

The closest solution to this problem is probably the Smart backspace feature, which will be present in IntelliJ IDEA 14. According to a comment in the blog post mentioned below it seems that the same functionality is planned for the Delete key, but it is probably not implemented yet.

- http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/07/the-backspace-key-gets-smarter-in-intellij-idea-14-eap/
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87318